# Has order of exports in Angular 2 / ts meaning?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-components

I go through an official tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html). And I have discovered, that the order of exports / @Components seems has value. So, if it is set so:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['styles.css'],
  templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'The untitled, unknown, unburried Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

but if I relocate the first export after @Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['styles.css'],
  templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
})

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'The untitled, unknown, unburried Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and exposes the error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    Error: Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1513:34)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14455:40)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14437:54)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25571:64)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25530:52)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25492:21)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4793:25)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4779:21)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:4:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/main.js
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1513:34)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14455:40)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14437:54)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25571:64)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25530:52)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25492:21)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4793:25)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4779:21)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:4:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/main.js
```

Does anybody knows why?

Comment: In your second example, you're annotating `Hero`, not `AppComponent` - that's the issue, not the class ordering. Annotations by definition are attached to the thing that comes after them.

Comment: I think it does not matter where you define your class. it seems it's different error

Answer (score 1):

It's because, as described by Angular component reference (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html), `@Component` is a decorator, which "
Marks a class as an Angular component and collects component configuration metadata." So you should put it before the class which is the component. If you put your `@Component` decorator just before your `Hero` class, you are marking that class as an Angular component, that's not correct.

The `Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'.` error comes because you declared `AppComponent` as a `Component` in your AppModule, and without the decorator, the app module does not recognize it anymore. Hope the explanation was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you might have been under the impression that `@Component` applies to the file as a whole. This isn't the case!

By definition, an annotation such as `@Component` *annotates* the thing that comes directly after it in the file.

In your second example, you're actually annotating `Hero`, not `AppComponent` - in other words, you're saying that `Hero` is a component!